# Swift 3 - Image view with Tap Gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, gesture

Im having issues with using a tap gesture that I have put on an image view. The image is currently stored in the Assets as 'ActionLiked' and I have set the image view to this image. It is then rendered into a table view which is dynamic based on JSON (so it repeats for each item I put into a JSON array). I added the tap gesture to print out 'TAPPED' each time I click on it however, it seems to not be working all the time - 7 items currently in the table, the tap gesture will work on 1 then not work on the next 2 then work on the 4th one and repeat that pattern

ITEM 1 - WORK
ITEM 2 - NO WORK
ITEM 3 - NO WORK
ITEM 4 - WORK
ITEM 5 - NO WORK
ITEM 6 - NO WORK
ITEM 7 - WORK

I get an error in my debug console
Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier
But the image is showing correctly on each one just not recognising the tap gesture?

Comment: please, show us some code...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Following code may help you more with Swift 4.

As you said you want to detect image tap on tableview cell please go through this code:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cellTappedMethod(_:)))

cell.yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.yourImageView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.yourImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

And add below method to your ViewController:

```
@objc func cellTappedMethod(_ sender:AnyObject){
     print("you tap image number: \(sender.view.tag)")
}
```

Comment: so when i try this i get an uncaught exception each time i press on the gesture


`let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsFeedVC.likePost(_:)))
self.actionLike.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.actionLike.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`

`func likePost(_ sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("TAPPED")
        
    }`

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-PostCell likePost:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbc3e894a00'

Comment: @Chad as you said you need this with tableview so in place of using self.actionLike for table view it is good to use cell.actionLike and to identify them you need to assign tag according to the index of the cell in tableview. and make sure the user interection for cell image is enable.

Answer (score 10):

Please check `isUserInteractionEnabled` of `UIImageView` is `true`

Answer (score 2):

I recently had an issue that seems similar to yours. I had a number of images, all of which I wanted to respond in the same way whenever the user tapped them. After some experimenting, it became clear to me that each image had to have its own `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance. I ended up using code like this, which ensured that every image responded to being tapped:

```
for imageView in imageViews {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapResponse))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The idea is that you should create unique gesture recognizer for every UIImageView.**

```
let gestureRecognizerOne = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
firstImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerOne)

let gestureRecognizerTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
secondImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizerTwo)
```

But I didn't see your code, so, maybe you should create it in a loop or something like that.